# Authenticating a single request with httpclient 4.x

Tags: java, authentication, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have an `HttpClient` instance that's shared by a number of threads. I would like to use it to make a single authenticated request. Because only the single request should be authenticated, I don't want to modify the `HttpClient` instance as described in the [documentation](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpclient/branches/4.0.x/httpclient/src/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientAuthentication.java).  Here's what I've worked out instead, which isn't working. From what I can tell, it doesn't look like the `CredentialsProvider` is being used at all. Any tips?

```
HttpContext context = null;
if(feedSpec.isAuthenticated()) {
  context = new BasicHttpContext();
  CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
  credsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials(feedSpec.getHttpUsername(), feedSpec.getHttpPassword()));
  context.setAttribute(ClientContext.CREDS_PROVIDER, credsProvider);
  context.setAttribute(ClientPNames.HANDLE_AUTHENTICATION, true);
}
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(feedSpec.getUri());
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet, context);
```

Comment: What kind of authentication are you using? BASIC, DIGEST, FORM ?

Comment: HttpClient 4 is an awful mess, IMO. It promised much, but it's stupidly hard to use for quite simple cases. I'm sticking with v3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out the server I was connecting to was only offering NTLM authentication. I implemented NTLM authentication using the guide [here](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/ntlm.html). I modified the code listed in my question to look like so and it works:

```
HttpContext context = null;
if(feedSpec.isAuthenticated()) {
    context = new BasicHttpContext();
    CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new NTCredentials(feedSpec.getHttpUsername(), feedSpec.getHttpPassword(), "", ""));
    context.setAttribute(ClientContext.CREDS_PROVIDER, credsProvider);
}
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(feedSpec.getUri());
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet, context);
```

Comment: The URL of the guide linked in this comment changed, and is now: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/ntlm.html